# How to set glpk solver parameters in openopt

Tags: python, optimization, glpk, cvxopt

I'm using the `openopt` library to solve a multi-constraint knapsack problem (http://openopt.org/KSP).

I'm using an external solver, specifically `GLPK`. I've installed everything correctly and I can successfully run the example script here: http://trac.openopt.org/openopt/browser/PythonPackages/OpenOpt/openopt/examples/ksp_2.py

My solve is taking quite a long time. Here is a recent output:

```
+1005281: mip =  -1.637283639e+03 >=  -1.655195650e+03   1.1% (267557; 116879)
```

I'm interested in setting the `GLPK` parameter for specifying MIP gap threshold as explained in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Terminal_output. I have a gap of 1% and I'd prefer to terminate the solve at this point. However I can't seem to set this parameter through `openopt`.